# excel: index and match with vba

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have this formula on the first column in my sheet:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Plan2!$A$1:$K$20;MATCH(Plan3!B2;Plan2!$B$1:$B$20;0);MATCH(Plan3!$A$1;Plan2!$A$1:$K$1;0));"")
```

[image]

And it fits perfectly for what I want: look up on Plan2 (my databse) for the information on column B of Plan3 by matching the result by matching the header of table.

What I want know is to translate this to a VBA that do the same thing. This is what I've tried so far:

```
Sub AlocSubs()

Dim i As Long
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet

Set ws1 = Sheets("Plan2")
Set ws2 = Sheets("Plan3")

For i = 2 To 20
    ws2.Cells(i, 1).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(ws1.Range("A1:K20"), .match(ws2.Range("B2"), ws1.Range("B1:B20"), 0), .match(ws2.Range("A1"), ws1.Range("A1:K1"), 0))
Next i

End Sub
```

When I try to run I get the message:

> Compilation error: Reference is not valid.

And I get this line highlighted:

```
Sub AlocSubs()
```

This is the first time that I try to translate a formula do a code in VBA so I really don't know what is going wrong.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: What's `.match(...)`? AFAIK that's not a proper way to call that...

Comment: @BruceWayne Actually with this question I was trying to figure it out if it's the correct way to use a formula in VBA, the match with formula is correct I was already using it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub AlocSubs()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim strFormula As String

    Set ws1 = Sheets("Plan2")
    Set ws2 = Sheets("Plan3")
    strFormula = "=IFERROR(INDEX(Plan2!$A$1:$K$20;MATCH(Plan3!B2;Plan2!$B$1:$B$20;0);MATCH(Plan3!$A$1;Plan2!$A$1:$K$1;0));"""")"

    With ws2
        With .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(20, 1))
            .Formula = strFormula
            .Value = .Value
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

**Note:** I've not tested your formula. Code shows how the formula result can be displayed using VBA.

Comment: If the goal is to use worksheet formulas to calculate the result and input the static result, you can shorten the code (and possibly speed it up) with [`Evaluate`](https://bettersolutions.com/excel/functions/vba-evaluate.htm). :)

Comment: @Vegard - `Evaluate` does shorten the code, you are right but I personally don't use evaluate because of the characters limitation though that's not the problem here.

Comment: @Mrig I got Run-time error 1004 in the line `.Formula = strFormula` when I tested...

Comment: @paulinhax - There might be issue with your formula, I've not tested it. Does your formula work on worksheet?

Comment: @Mrig yes! in the print that illustrate the post, I'm already using it and it's working fine.

Comment: @paulinhax - Let me check and I'll get back to you.

Comment: @paulinhax - There's change at the end of formula `;"")"` should be `;"""")"`. Missed the double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You used `.match`, but you don't have `With` statement before. You also don't use `i` in your formula. I guess it should be like this:

```
With Application.WorksheetFunction
    For i = 2 To 20
        ws2.Cells(i, 1).Value = .Index(ws1.Range("A1:K20"), .Match(ws2.Range("B" & i), ws1.Range("B1:B20"), 0), .Match(ws2.Range("A1"), ws1.Range("A1:K1"), 0))
    Next i
End With
```

Comment: Code will fail at execution if `match` doesn't find anything. You'll need to either introduce an error catcher or use `Application.Match` instead of `Application.WorksheetFunction.Match`.

Comment: I tested this code and when I run it I get `Run-time error 1004:` it doesn't recognize the match function.